# I have 2 SSDs one for windows the other for ubuntu. No grub on sda

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, hard-drive

I installed Windows 8 on `sda` and I installed Xubuntu on `sdb`, but I don't like using Ubuntu grub to change sda mbr. I like to use a simple F12 solution for dual boot. How can I remove grub on `sda` and install grub only on `sdb`?

What should I do?

When I boot Windows 8 on `sda`, I don't want to see any grub screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Windows 8 and Ubuntu. To install grub into `sdb` you have to choose the partition to install boot-loader as `sdb`. Since you already installed Xubuntu, you can use Boot-Repair tool to reinstall grub on `sdb`.

Having said that, neither during installation nor with Boot-Repair I could manage to place grub on `sdb`. No matter what I choose they placed grub on EFI partition in `sda`. Then I physically disconnected my first HDD (`sda`), there was no other choice and installer had to place grub on `sdb`. You can also try creating a second EFI partition on `sdb` during installation and see if that works out.

Removing grub from `sda` is tricky. For me, `fixmbr` did not solve the problem since it only reinstalls Windows boot manager. You may have to go and manually delete grub on EFI partition. Otherwise It will just copy itself to BIOS in every restart.

To do this:

- run command line on Windows as administrator
- run `diskpart` tool
- `list volume`

After this, it will list your hard drives. Select the one your OS's are on.

- `select volume 0` (0 for first hard drive etc.)
- `list partition`
- `select partition 0` (select EFI partition, usually first partition. So 0. EFI partition should be the one no letter assigned to it)
- `assign letter=Z` (or some other letter, this makes EFI partition visible in Windows explorer)
- `exit` (exit diskpart)

Now you have run explorer as administrator to access EFI drive:

- `taskkill /im explorer.exe /f` (kill explorer)
- `explorer.exe` restart explorer as administrator

Now you can go to your Drive Z: (EFI partition) and delete ubuntu folder which contains grub.

At the end, start `diskpart` again repeat the same procedure to `remove letter=Z` and make EFI partition invisible again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to:

- Boot with the Windows 8 repair disk
- Repair `sda`
- Use the BIOS to boot